# Unable to show the Binding Result errors in JSP (Spring MVC)

Tags: spring-mvc

Hi I am using Spring MVC and Hibernate. I have one controller and the corresponding validator

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void validate(Class<?> argClass, Errors argErrors,
        Object argObject) {
    List<Field> calidationFieldsList = AnnotationProcessor
            .getAnnotatedFields(argClass, Validation.class);
    if (Precondition.checkNotEmpty(calidationFieldsList)) {
        for (Field field : calidationFieldsList) {
            try {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object result;
                result = field.get(argObject);

                Object instance = getValidatorInstance(argClass, field);
                if (Precondition.checkNotNull(instance)
                        && Precondition.checkNotNull(result)) {
                    com.rise.validation.Validation<String, String> validation = (com.rise.validation.Validation<String, String>) instance;
                    boolean valid = validation.validate(result.toString());
                    if (!valid) {
                        argErrors.rejectValue(field.getName(),
                                field.getName() + " Validation Failed");
                    }
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code validates all my fields. Below is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = HibernateConstants.SAVE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(Model argModel, @Valid Person argPerson,
        org.springframework.validation.BindingResult argBindingResult) {
    if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
        logger.trace("################################# Entered into PersonController Save Method: #################################");
    }
    if (argBindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return HibernateConstants.VIEW_SLASH + getSimpleName()
                + HibernateConstants.PERSON;
    }
    Person person = (Person) this.getBaseService().save(argPerson);
    argModel.addAttribute(getSimpleName(), person);
    return HibernateConstants.VIEW_SLASH + getSimpleName()
            + HibernateConstants.VIEW;
}
```

Here If BindingResult has any errors I will forward to that page in that I am using spring form errors tag to show the errors(). But I was unable to see those errors.

Can any one help me on this. Is there any thing I missed...?

**Note:** My controller and my validations class both are different.

Can any one point me to the right path.

Thanq
Amar

Comment: Let me understand. If `argBindingResult.hasErrors()` is `true`, you return some string value (please show what that value is). Then what? You would like to see those errors in there?

Comment: Hay If that Binding result has errors then I am not saving the record and I am just returning to the same page. I am expecting the errors in the JSP page.

Comment: What is the exact value of `HibernateConstants.VIEW_SLASH + getSimpleName() + HibernateConstants.PERSON;`?

Comment: /view/person/person (/view is the folder name it has all jsps/views, /person its also a folder- each entity CRUD operations related jsps will store the corresponding folder and the last one is jsp name).

Comment: So what you are returning is a view name. Based on your registered `ViewResolver`, this would probably be a jsp. Why do you expect the errors to be there?

Comment: I am validating some fields. If the validation fails I need to show that errors on top of that field. How can I show those binding results into my jsp...?